# Verifying $y=\frac{4}{1+Ce^{-t}}$ is a solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-\frac{y}{4})$ for $C≥0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to verify that $y=\frac{4}{1+Ce^{-t}}$ is a solution of $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-\frac{y}{4})$ for $C≥0$. What I have done is differentiate $y$ which gave me:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{4}{(1+Ce^{-t})^2}$$

But I'm not sure how I can rearrange this to make it equal $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-\frac{y}{4})$, nor how to prove that this works only for $C≥0$.

Comment: Next multiply $y$ times $(1-y/4)$ and compare

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: you know what $y$ is. You've already computed its derivative. Can you also compute $(1-y/4)$?

Comment: Still not sure how to get $(1-\frac{y}{4})$

Comment: first divide by 4. Go in pemdas order

Comment: Divide what by 4?

Comment: to compute $y/4$ first you start with $y$ and you divide it by 4.  That's what the slash means. You have an expression for $y$. You used it to take the derivative. You can also use it to divide by 4.

Comment: Okay I got that. Now I'm not sure what to do with it

Comment: next subtract $y/4$ from 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You differentiated wrong.
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{4C\mathrm{e}^{-t}}{\left(1+C\mathrm{e}^{-t}\right)^2} = C\mathrm{e}^{-t}\frac{y^2}{4}=\left(\frac{4}{y}-1\right)\frac{y^2}{4}
$$
Finish off by multiplying through.

Comment: How does $Ce^{-t}=(1-\frac{4}{y})$?

Comment: You were right - I had a sign go wrong.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now, I got it